# Как обновить данные в chart js?

Tags: javascript, диаграммы, chart.js

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart1').getContext('2d');
            var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: "line",
                data: {
                    labels: [1, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 7],
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 255, 42, 0.1)",
                            borderColor: "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.8)",
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            data: this.chart1,
                        },
                    ],
                },
                options: chartOptions
            });
```

Как обновить график ? В this.chart1 приходят данные, но они не обновляют график, помогает только перезагрузка страницы, подскажите пожалуйста как принудительно обновить ?